# Copy Android MTP files using linux terminal or python; error Operation not supported

Tags: android, python, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

i'm trying to create my own python script to backup Android images.i can see the Android mounted well, and i can move files back and forth using nautilus but not from CLI

the CLI error is "Operation not supported"

```
hkhrais@Hkhrais:/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C006%5D/Phone/Download$ cp  DSC03951.JPG /home/hkhrais/Desktop/

cp: cannot open ‘DSC03951.JPG’ for reading: Operation not supported
```

python code

```
try:
            shutil.copyfile('/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C006%5D/Phone/Download/DSC03951.JPG', "/home/hkhrais/Desktop/test")

except:
    raise


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scriptt.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "scriptt.py", line 18, in main
    shutil.copyfile(img, "/home/hkhrais/Desktop/test")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C006%5D/Phone/Download/DSC03951.JPG'
```

Android 4.2.2 
Python 2.7
Ubuntu 14.4

any idea or alternative way please ?

Comment: I think Nautlius is probably using [libmtp](http://libmtp.sourceforge.net/) to copy the files under the covers. You probably need to use something like [pymtp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMTP) to do it from Python.

Answer (score 5):

Use `gvfs-copy` instead of `cp`. For example:

`gvfs-copy "mtp://[usb:002,06]/Phone/Download/DSC03951.JPG" /home/hkhrais/Desktop/`

For executing this command in python you can use `os.system`:

```
import os
os.system('gvfs-copy "mtp://[usb:002,06]/Phone/Download/DSC03951.JPG" /home/hkhrais/Desktop/')
```

Comment: I get `operation not supported` -- Wonder if it is a security problem?

Comment: [check out python's suprocess module] (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)

i was able to successfully transfer .mp3s from my Ubuntu 16.04 machine to my Android phone using `suprocess.check_call()` with `shell=True` like this:

`cmd = 'cp "{src}" "{dest}"'.format(
        src=source_path,
        dest=dest_path)
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)`

Caveat: When you use `shell=True` it's up to you to protect from shell injection: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations

Comment: Nowadays it's `gio copy` instead of gvfs-copy.

Answer (score 2):

try using ptp (I got the same error when using MTP) but PTP worked. from settings you can change how android phone appears to your computer when the device is connects, android 5 hast two options, PTP and MTP.